# What is a disambiguating keyword template?

Tags: c++

I am reading about [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) and encountered the following sentence:

> If the name appears immediately to the right of the scope resolution
>   operator :: or possibly after :: followed by the disambiguating
>   keyword template

I do get the first part of the above, but "after :: followed by ***the disambiguating keyword template*** - whaaatt? I am lost on this one.

So what is a *"disambiguating keyword* and what is a *"keyword template"* (the author has written this as if they are one thing, at least to me)?

Comment: `template` is a *keyword* that is used to *disambiguate* the name.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x in that case, shouldn't it be "template keyword" and not "keyword template"? :/

Comment: And how does template  _disambiguate_ a name? Like what make that keyword disambiguate the name?

Comment: I made a comment on Soronel's answer; I don't know what else to tell you. Its part of the language. There are situations where `<something>::name` isn't clear, especially with specializations. Using `template` in this manner makes it clear to the compiler that you're intending to use `name` as a template.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    template<typename U> static void foo(){}
};

template<typename T>
void bar()
{
    S<T>::foo<T>(); // error: < parsed as less than operator
    S<T>::template foo<T>(); // OK
}

int main() {
    bar<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

[More details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)

Answer (score 0):

it is referring to:

```
typename A::template b<foo>::type
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but how is that "disambiguating"?

Comment: @step there are situations where the syntax `<something>::name` could be ambiguous to what `name` refers to. The keyword, `template`, is used to clarify that `name` is a template.